# Access table in other than default scheme (database) from sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

After I managed it to connect to our (new) cluster using `sparklyr` with `yarn-client` method, now I can show just the tables from the default scheme. How can I connect to `scheme.table`?
Using `DBI` it's working e.g. with the following line:
`dbGetQuery(sc, "SELECT * FROM scheme.table LIMIT 10")`
In HUE, I can show all tables from all schemes.

~g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use a fully qualified name to register temporary view:

```
spark_session(sc) %>% 
  invoke("table", "my_database.my_table") %>%
  invoke("createOrReplaceTempView", "my_view")

tbl(sc, "my_view")
```

or use `sql` method to switch databases

```
spark_session(sc) %>% invoke("sql", "USE my_database")
```

and access table directly with `dplyr:tbl`:

```
tbl(sc, "my_table")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the second option, which worked fine for me.

Comment: Just a heads up to avoid confusion: if you've already loaded the tidyverse, purrr::invoke() will override sparklyr::invoke() unless the function is prefixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DBI's`dbgetQuery` to change the database. This is useful bc it will also update your view in Connections to the specific data base rather than the default.

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "use <database>")
```

Lastly you can just reference the database within a tbl statement

```
dplyr::tbl(sc,"want_db.have_data") %>% ...
```

Comment: `DBI::dbSendQuery` would more appropriate as you are not collecting any data.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use tbl_change_db to change the default database for the session.

e.g.:

```
tbl_change_db("other_db")
```